# Works in OS 2.2.1 but not in OS 3.0: Error: type of accessor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-2

Does Anyone have any idea why this code produces this errors in OS 3.0 and not OS 2.2.1?

```
NSUInteger aCount = [serverBrowser.servers count];
```

error: type of accessor does not match the type of property 'servers'

ServerBrowser.h is define below and serverBrowser is synthesized in .m above.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @class ServerBrowserDelegate;

    @interface ServerBrowser : NSObject {
      NSMutableArray* servers;
      id<ServerBrowserDelegate> delegate;
    }

    @property(nonatomic,readonly) NSArray* servers;


    @end
```

Thanks in advance for the help. Much appreciated.
Jordan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the fact that you provide the `@property` for the `servers` array as an `NSArray*`, but declare the backing instance variable as an `NSMutableArray*`. The OS 3.0 compiler may just come with stricter compiler settings than 2.2.1. Try converting to:

```
@property(nonatomic,readonly) NSMutableArray *servers;
```

Comment: absolutely right, I can't believe I didn't catch that (smile). I got hung up on the code, since it worked in 2.2.1. Good one @Tim. Cheers!